# RMAN ORACLE issue

Tags: oracle, performance, backup, rman, oracle-19c

I have the issue when I run the command RMAN as mentioned below :

[image]
Please any help

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @mustaccio oky thank you

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved after I added these two  parameters to `listener.ora` :

```
DIRECT_HANDOFF_TTC_LISTENER=OFF
INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER=0
```